# How to publish an app that requires custom device on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

My brand new app requires a custom device to connect to it via BLE.
the main screen is a "batteries radar" that scans for our own batteries advertisements.

Because such a device is not present while Google play automatically test my app, the radar remains empty and they rose the  accessibility issue because of the lack of interactive links.

What should I do?

Is there anything I have to do to provide them with a device?
Does this could block the release to hit the store?

Comment: "What should I do?" -- perhaps add a more detailed onboarding experience and a better "empty state" in the no-custom-device-available experience. IOW, improve the user experience for all users in these cases, with a side benefit of helping Google evaluators understand what they are seeing. Beyond that, though, [questions about app distribution channel policies are off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare and sorry for having written an off topic question